# Parameterized Input with Document Fields with Cosmos DB

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to use Parameterized Queries with a Document Field as well as with the value at a specified Field for Cosmos DB. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#parameterized-queries

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Families f
WHERE @field = @value
```

I want to be able to specify something like `f.lastName` for `@field`, and `Smith` for `@value`.

Is this not possible? Trying to do this over the .NET SDK, it doesn't seem to work, no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

You can use the [Quoted Property Accessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#EscapingReservedKeywords)

Here is how you'd do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Families f
WHERE f[@field] = @value
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#parameterized-queries), `@field = @value` is not supported.

```
SELECT *
    FROM Families f
    WHERE f.lastName = @lastName AND f.address.state = @addressState
```

If your filter column is flexible, you could splicing  query sql as String by yourself.

```
'SELECT *
FROM Families f
WHERE ' + filterColumn + ' = @value'
```

Comment: I could, but I wanted to use parameterized queries to avoid sql injection.

Comment: @Neko Never heard about parameterization of filter column, only filter value need to be parameterized. If follow your idea, then the `where,select, Families f`all need to be parameterized,are they?

Comment: @Neko Hi,any updates?Does my answer helps you?If so,you could mark it for answer.Thank you.